# fo:block next to fo:table in xsl

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

how can I put a fo:block with a text like:

```
     <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="48pt">
        HALLO
    </fo:block>
```

side by side / next to a my fo:table in the xsl file.

My XSL File looks so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:date="java.util.Date" xmlns:sf="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"
  exclude-result-prefixes="java" version="1.0">
....
....
...

  <xsl:template match="Order">
    <fo:table border="0.5pt solid">
      <fo:table-column column-width="5cm"/>
          <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-size="10pt">
             delivery:
            </fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="12pt">
              <xsl:value-of select="@DeliveryTime"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Next to the table above in my xsl sheet I want to put the HALLO text.

Comment: What should the result look like? Are you producing XSL-FO via an XSLT stylesheet? If so, show the input XML and the XSLT code. What FO processor are you using, and which version of it?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I'm using a stylesheet version 1.0.
*UPDATE*

Comment: Your post is still missing an XML input file, the FO processor and version used and a clearer description of the desired result. Any reason why you cannot simply put the text inside another `fo:table-cell` to the right?

Comment: I did this, but the text HALLO is too big and so the whole row where I add the new cell would be enlarged. That does'nt look so good...

Comment: You can always span cells if you need more room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want this, you can specify a block-container that contains two block-containers with absolute positions placed side by side. The table goes in one, the text goes in the other.
But it's probably simpler to extend the table across the full page width and place the 'Hallo' text inside a cell, and span/merge cells if you need more room.